# value column in other column containing list of values

Tags: python, pandas

Column A contains strings. Column B contains list of strings.
I would like to know how many times is the value of A in the column B.

I have

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| k | `[m]` |
| c | `[k,l,m]` |
| j | `[k,l]` |
| e | `[e,m]` |
| e | `[e,m,c,e]` |

I would like this output:

| C |
| --- |
| 0 |
| 0 |
| 0 |
| 1 |
| 2 |

Comment: what are these values based on?

Comment: each letter is just a string value

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use `apply` on `row` then use `.count` list like below.
Try this:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['k', 'c', 'j', 'e', 'e'],'B': [['m'],['k','l','m'],['k','l'],['e','m'],['e','m','c','e']]})
>>> df['C'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['B'].count(row['A']), axis=1)
>>> df

           A    B               C
0          k    [m]             0
1          c    [k, l, m]       0
2          j    [k, l]          0
3          e    [e, m]          1
4          e    [e, m, c, e]    2
```